# Preserving state across pages in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have the following widget tree on two pages A and B.

```
Hero
|-SomeStatelessWidget
  |-SomeStatefulWidget
```

Tapping on the widget triggers navigation from page A to page B. However, state for `SomeStatefulWidget` is recreated after the transition. How can I preserve the state of `SomeStatefulWidget` across page navigation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GlobalKey](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html) to preserve the same state across different pages.

```
class RandomColor extends StatefulWidget {
  RandomColor({Key key}) : super(key: key); // need this

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => RandomColorState();
}
```

Here you have a great [Google Developers video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc) about keys.

You may also consider using some kind of [state managment](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt).

Comment: Sorry I meant GlobalKey, not PageStorageKey, which keeps different state per page